# Store XML Data in Near Protocol

Tags: nearprotocol

I need to store and retrieve XML-Data in a Near Protocol Blockchain and I have never done anything with Blockchains before.
How do I start and what do I need?
I tried to learn about Smart Contracts and about Blocks in a Blockchain. But I am not sure how I should start and whats some.

Answer (score 2):

NEAR supports storing data as key-value pairs. If you work with XML, you have to manually serialize/deserialize your data structures.

Notice the concept of smart-contracts, the data is stored as part of the contracts state.
Read more about state and storage:
https://docs.near.org/concepts/basics/accounts/state#contracts-state
https://docs.near.org/concepts/storage/data-storage

Also notice that NEAR SDKs (for JavaScript and Rust) abstract away from you the inner workings of the blockchain, so you don’t need to worry about these advanced concept when just getting started.

If you’re new to blockchain and NEAR, I suggest following a few tutorials and articles on NEAR Docs site: https://docs.near.org/

A good tutorial that demonstrates storage utilization is the Guest Book tutorial: https://docs.near.org/tutorials/examples/guest-book